# Excerpt displays the current page excerpt not one being pulled

Tags: excerpt

Just as the title says this code is not pulling the excerpt from $recent like it should be, instead it is pulling it from the current page.

```
   <?php
$args = array( 'post_status' => 'pending');
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
$recent->the_post(); // Add this here to cause the other functions to work without the post ID
    echo '<div id="votes"><li id="voteimage"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . esc_attr( $recent["post_title"] ) . '">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail');
    echo '</li></a>';
    echo '<li class="vote-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li>';
    echo '<li class="vote-desc"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</a> </li>';
    echo '</div><br></br>';
}

?>
```

`get_the_excerpt($recent["ID"])` is the part pulling the excerpts, tried using the_excerpts and swapping it around to `($recent[get_the_excerpt])` too, nothing I try seems to work.

Example: [streakingpirates.com](http://streakingpirates.com/pending/)

Comment: Inside your loop, add `$recent->the_post()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs, the parameter to pass the post ID is marked `deprecated`.

That means, in order for your custom loop to work, you need to add `$recent->the_post()`

**However**, as you pointed out, you can't do that when you use `wp_get_posts`, so I'd suggest modifying the query to be a custom loop:

```
$args = array( 'post_status' => 'pending');
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then, you should be able to use your code:

See below:

```
while ( $recent_posts->have_posts()) {
    $recent_posts->the_post(); // Add this here to cause the other functions to work without the post ID
    echo '<div id="votes"><li id="voteimage"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . esc_attr( $recent["post_title"] ) . '">';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail');
    echo '</li></a>';
    echo '<li class="vote-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li>';
    echo '<li class="vote-desc"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</a> </li>';
    echo '</div><br></br>';
}
```

**Also note** that `get_the_excerpt()` will return un-filtered content.  You may want to wrap it in an `apply_filters()` like so:

```
apply_filters('the_content', get_the_excerpt());
```

Comment: Sadly that's causing an error message on the same line I placed it http://streakingpirates.com/pending/ that's the error

Comment: @PirateScott - shoot.  I was worried about that.  Thankfully, that should be a simple fix - check my edits in a moment.

Comment: Error is still there, my new code is now up in the top. I should say my knowledge of PHP and the wordpress functions is lacking, I only started with both properly 2 days ago.

Comment: @PirateScott - OK, time to make the "Full swap" of code to properly use the `WP_Query`.  Please see my edits in a moment... thanks for your patience!

Comment: You are a star, thanks. It worked but the title doesnt show now, I think I know what the problem to that is though